# Numpy, getting indices of subarrays of a 1darray that are of a specific size with numpy.where()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list (list_of_peaks) and an 1darray (data). The array contains time series data including the values that are in the list. I would wish to find elements in the array between two values upstream and downstream of the elements in the list (in this case +-100 arbitrary units). I used numpy.union1d to define the range and then np.split to split the data. This gives me a list of 1darrays, I would wish to get the indices of the arrays that have a size smaller than 200.

```
peak_range = np.union1d(list_of_peaks + 100, list_of_peaks - 100)
split_data_test_w_extra = np.split(data, peak_range)
split_data_test_w_extra = np.array(split_data_test_w_extra)
index_200 = np.where(split_data_test_w_extra.size <= 200)
```

numpy.where() returns an empty array `(array([], dtype=int64),)`. I tried also tried converting the array of arrays to a boolean array where the condition was the size of the subarray but also without luck. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Look at `split_data_test_w_extra.size`.  How many values?  how many values relative to 200?  `where/nonzero` is not iterator.  It just finds the `True` values in its array argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're searching for the indices of the arrays that have a size smaller than 200, you're missing 1 step, which is mapping the `.size` attribute to each array in `split_data_test_w_extra`.

```
peak_range = np.union1d(list_of_peaks + 100, list_of_peaks - 100)
split_data_test_w_extra = np.split(data, peak_range)
split_data_test_w_extra = np.array(split_data_test_w_extra)
index_200 = np.where(np.array(list(map(lambda sub_arr: sub_arr.size, split_data_test_w_extra))) <= 200)
```

alternatively, you can use list comprehension

```
index_200 = [idx for idx, sub_arr in enumerate(split_data_test_w_extra) if sub_arr.size <= 200]
```